# How to make an HTTP head request with headers in ruby?

Tags: ruby, https, http-headers

I've been trying to use several libraries to make an HTTP HEAD request, but nothing seems to be working.

I've seen some examples, but nothing quite what I want.

Here's the Curl request, now I have to do it in ruby:

```
curl -XHEAD -H x-auth-user: myusername -H x-auth-key: mykey "url"
```

Also, this is an HTTPS url, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'net/http'

url = 'http://...'
myusename = '...'
mykey = '...'

request = Net::HTTP.new(url, 80)
request.request_head('/', 'x-auth-user' => myusername, 'x-auth-key' => my_key)
```